# Como faço para deletar valias linhas do BD que contenham uma palavra especifica?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, porém ele só exclui uma única linha, eu gostaria de deletar todas as linhas que contenham a palavra "exemplo":

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST["id"])){
    
        function deletar($id_user){
            $delete = mysql_query("delete from itens where chave='exemplo'");
        }

        deletar($id);
    }  
    else {

        echo "Erro ao deletar: " . $conn->error;

    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Precisa ver o que faz a função `deletar($id)`

Comment: consegui amigo colocando LIKE %exemplo%, obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simples, usa o "**Like**" em vez de "**=**" 
Na mais básica explicação, o Like serve para "comparação" entre Strings , e o "=" Serve para comparação entre Números. 
Para uma informação mais detalhada recomendo que leias esta discussão https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like